# 2 loops on page - one with orderby rand second orderby date

Tags: wp-query, loop, query-posts

What I'm trying to achive, is to set 2 loops on one page. **First one** takes 11 latest posts and sort them in rand order. **Second** show the rest of posts ordered by date.

***FIRST LOOP***

```
$args = array('posts_per_page' => 11,'orderby' => 'rand' , 'order' => 'ASC');
$loop = new WP_Query($args);
$do_not_duplicate[] = $post->ID;

while ($loop-> have_posts()) : $loop->the_post();
$do_not_duplicate[] = $post->ID;
```

***SECOND LOOP***

```
$args2 = array('posts_per_page' => 22, 'paged' => $paged, 'post__not_in' => $do_not_duplicate, 'orderby' => 'date', 'order' => 'ASC', 'max_num_pages' => 5);
$loop2 = new WP_Query($args2);

while ($loop2-> have_posts()) : $loop2->the_post();
```

My problem is that the second loop should show the same posts in same order after every refresh, unfortunately it's not. Any advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With some clues from @PieterGoosen I've found working solution.

**First loop**

```
$argsR = array(
      'numberposts' => 11,
      'fields'         => 'ids'
    );

$latest_posts =  get_posts( $argsR );
shuffle( $latest_posts );


$args = array('posts_per_page' => 11,
              'post__in' => $latest_posts , 
              'orderby' => 'post__in', 
              'order' => 'ASC');

$loop = new WP_Query($args);
$do_not_duplicate[] = $post->ID;

while ($loop-> have_posts()) : $loop->the_post();
    $do_not_duplicate[] = $post->ID;
```

So, first loop shows 11 most recent posts in random order and pushes each post ID to `$do_not_duplicate[]`array which I use to exclude most recent posts from second loop.

**Second loop**

```
$args2 = array(
    'posts_per_page' =>-1, 
    'post__not_in' => $do_not_duplicate, 
    'orderby' => 'date', 
    'order' => 'ASC');

$loop2 = new WP_Query($args2);
$num_of_posts = $loop->post_count;
while ($loop2-> have_posts()) : $loop2->the_post();
```

Having two seperate loops lets me paginate second posts list as I needed.

Comment: You should accept your own answer, if you do not know how or are not sure, please take your time and read ["What should I do when someone answers my question?"](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers). ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, don't forget the `<?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>` between loops. I remember getting stumped on that the first time I ran multiple queries on a page.

Comment: `wp_reset_query()` should be `wp_reset_postdata()`. `wp_reset_query()` is used with `query_posts` which you must never use

Answer (score 2):

Getting posts randomly is quite expensive and should be avoided where needed. I think we can do this in a better way.

- Lets query all posts at once, regardless, sorted by date. WE will only query ID's which should be extremely quick
- Store the query results (*post ID's*) in two variables
- Shuffle the one array of ID's to randomize them and then get the first 11 ID's
- We will then remove those 11 ID's from the second array and get 22 ID's
- Merge the two arrays and run our final query

Lets try the following code

```
$args = [ // ADJUST THESE AS NEEDED
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'order'          => 'ASC',
    'fields'         => 'ids' // Only get post ID's, this also bypass object caches
];
$array_1 = $array_2 = get_posts( $args );
// Make sure we have posts and we have more than 11 posts
if (    $array_1
     && 11 < count( $array_1 )
) {  
    // Shuffle the first array
    shuffle( $array_1 );
    // Get the first 11 entries sorted randomly
    $array_1_random = array_slice( $array_1, 0, 11 ); 
    // Remove the entries from $array_1_random from $array_2
    $difference     = array_diff( $array_2, $array_1_random );
    // Get the first 22 entries from $difference
    $diff_22_IDs    = array_slice( $difference, 0, 22 ); 
    // Merge the two arrays, $array_1_random and $diff_22_IDs
    $ids = array_merge( $array_1_random, $diff_22_IDs );

    // Now that we have our ID's sorted to suite our needs, query the posts
    $last_args = [ // DO NOT ADJUST THESE, SHOULD BE FINE
        'post__in'       => $ids,
        'orderby'        => 'post__in',
        'order'          => 'ASC',
        'posts_per_page' => count( $ids )
    ];
    $q = new WP_Query( $last_args );

    // Output your loop
    while ( $q->have_posts() ) {
        $q->the_post();

        the_title();

    }
    wp_reset_postdata(); // VERY VERY IMPORTANT
}
```

### A FEW NOTES

- Adjust the code as needed. You should have to change anything in `$last_args` though
- You said you needed one page, so there is no need to set the `paged` parameter as we will not paginate. If you require pagination, you would need to adjust my code slightly
- `'max_num_pages'` is not a valid parameter

Comment: thanks for your comprehensive answer. Unfortunately I need to keep two seperate loops because of pagination.  However, I found some clues in your in your solution

Comment: You should post your final code with explanation as an answer and accrpt your own answer ;-)

Comment: I did. Below. http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/219885/89711

Answer (score 1):

The second query will not always show the same posts, as it is dependend on the first query, which is random.

For example, you got 50 posts (ID 1 to 50, ordered by date).

First run:

First query takes 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11 and passes those IDs to the second query, so the second query will show 12,13,14,...

Second run:

The first query randomly selects IDs 39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50, and the second query will return IDs 1-22.

Please be also sure to call `wp_reset_postdata()` to ensure the correct behaviour of all queries. (thanks @PieterGoosen :) )

Comment: `wp_reset_query()` should be `wp_reset_postdata()`